# Demora en plotear dos columnas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hola estoy trabajando con dos columnas que tienen 85.000 filas. Para plotear punto por punto `python` se demora demasiado.

¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Más o menos mi código es este:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig_size = [20, 18]
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = fig_size
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = pd.read_csv('mínimos.txt')
x = data.iloc[:,0]
y = data.iloc[:,1]
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

Alguna ayuda.

Comment: Rocker, te comento dos cosas: 1.- En donde dice "data = pd.read_csv('mínimos'.txt)", debería ser "data = pd.read_csv('mínimos.txt')". 2.- Podrías compartir un ejemplo del archivo mínimos.txt? Eso nos ayudaría a reproducir el problema.

Comment: Ya lo corregí, es muy largo el archivo

Comment: Ten en cuanta que tiene que leer los datos de un archivo de texto (lo cual ya no es lo más eficiente del mundo para almacenar grandes cantidades de datos), parsear cada linea y convertir cada columna al tipo que corresponda cargando todos el contenido en RAM y luego generar la gráfica (matplotlib tampoco ha sido diseñado para ser lo más eficiente del mundo, sino para generar gráficas de calidad para publicaciones)... ¿El archivo tiene más columnas aparte de las dos que usas? Lo digo porque en ese caso, si no las usas para otra cosa es una perdida de recursos importante parsearlas

Comment: Entonces que puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Lo que tienes es un csv con solo dos columnas de escalares (float o int)? Es para hacer algunos test...

Comment: Una es por formato de horas y la otra flotantes

Comment: Estoy superponiendo dos gráficos de dos archivos csv diferentes, para mostrar el plot se demora.

Comment: Comparte el archivo subiéndolo a github y lo añades a la pregunta.